# Multi-word $GET variable problemin PHP

Tags: php, variables, get, explode, implode

I am currently writing some search engine, where this page is retrieving some _GET variables from a previous page. This is working as intended.

Now I am using those variables as default value in a POST form. However, for some reason, only the first word for each of them is showing up. The form code is as follows:

```
<form action = "insert.php" method = 'POST'>
<Place name <input type="text" name="name" size = "30" value= <?php echo $_GET['name']; ?> />
```

Note that when echoing $_GET['name'] anywhere else in the page, everything is fine. Multiple words show up as expected, but when I use it as a text box default value, only the first word shows up on the textbox.

At first, I thought it had something to do with the way those $_GET variables are sent in the URL so I tried this:

```
$fullname = array();

 $fullname = explode("%20", $_GET['name']);

 $aaa = implode (' ',$fullname);
```

...

```
Place name <input type="text" name="name" size = "30" value= <?php echo $aaa; ?> />
```

but the result is still the same. If I echo it anywhere else in the page I get the full string, but if it's inside the form only the first word shows up.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you do a `print_r($_GET)`, you will see that PHP decodes the querystring for you, and there will not be a `%20` in your string (unless of course there is a double-escaped `%20` in the actual query string).  Your problem is that you are not using quotes in your HTML tags, generating invalid HTML.  You're also not using `htmlspecialchars()` in your output, meaning you are not properly escaping the data potentially leading to invalid HTML and XSS attacks.

Answer (score 5):

The `value` attribute of the input tag needs to be in quotes:

```
<input type="text" name="name" size = "30" value="<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>" />"
```

Otherwise, if `$_GET['name']` contains spaces you'll end up with something like: `value=John Smith`.  That will be understood as `value=John` with an invalid `Smith` attribute floating around.

Also, consider sanitizing `$_GET['name']` with [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars).  Consider what would happen if `$_GET['name']` was `"/><script>alert(0)</script><`.  You'd end up embedding user-controlled code on your website, resulting in a [reflected XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29).

Comment: -1, This code is subject to XSS attacks.  Use `htmlspecialchars()` around any arbitrary data used in the context of HTML.

Comment: @Brad - I was in the process of editing the answer to include that.

Comment: ahh thanks! I figured it would be something simple like this.